# Which method of NLP is this?

Tags: nlp

I have been searching for 2 weeks and I got no where so far.

There is  a list of diseases

```
Diabetes 
Heart Transplant
Fingertip amputation
Injury by sharp tools
.
.
.
```

and My dataset is a list of medical text reports.

the training dataset has diseases that can be generated from each record

example that I made

> This patient has suffered a cut while using his Carving Chisel and led
>   to losing the fingertip therefore we had to operate to sew
>   the tip.....

from this report we get these diseases

```
1- Injury by sharp tools
2- Fingertip amputation
3- Sewing injury
```

another report results may have 3 or less or more diseases

I have searched a lot
I found many examples about NLP classification

where a text will be classified into Sports, Politics, Culture, Science, etc.

I found NER where person names, locations, dates, etc can be extracted from a text.

But did not find anything for a single text could have multiple values (similar to my dataset)

I dont know where to start.

Could anyone please help me finding what is the name of this method of extracting list of issues from a text?

**Edit**

What else do I need to exclude the negations, if the report says

> "This patient has stomach problem but not diabetes "

How can I make AI understand there is a negation (**NOT**) before diabetes so it should not be included?

So the result will be

```
stomach problem
```

as diabetes should be excluded because of the negation word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want  to look at [Multi-Label-Classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification) . If you have sufficient number of samples as your training data, you can build a model that can predict more than one label for a test sample. You can find more about the implementation at the sklearn page for the same [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) .

Comment: Thanks heaps, what else do I need to exclude the negations, if the report says "This patient has stomach problem but not diabetes " How can I make AI understand there is a negation (NOT) before diabetes so it should not be included?

Comment: The idea is if you have enough samples like these, you can count on the models to learn this automatically. If you want to create features, you can create bigram features that will help the model distinguish diabetes vs not diabetes.

Answer (score 1):

This task would be very close to [topic modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topic_model), which is usually addressed as a multi-label classification problem.